# CSS Grid auto-fit + minmax only wraps the last element

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a responsive footer using grid and it's almost working but not quite. When the screen is wide everything's spaced out perfectly. Once the screen size gets smaller, the items should start wrapping onto the next implicit row. At least that's what happened in a video guide I watched.

In my case though, for some reason only the last item wraps to the next row while the rest of them stay static causing overflow and horizontal scrolling. I've been trying to figure out what's going for a few hours now but no luck. Am I not seeing something? Please help.

```css
.footer__logo {
  width: 40px;
  margin-bottom: var(--spacer-xs);
}

.footer__header {
  margin-bottom: var(--spacer-xs);
}

.contact-us {
  margin-top: var(--spacer-xs);
}

.footer__unit--last {
  align-self: end;
}

.footer-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container footer-grid">
    <div class="footer__unit">
      <h3 class="footer__header">Abstract</h3>
      <ul class="footer__list">
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Start Trial</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Download</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer__unit">
      <h3 class="footer__header">Resources</h3>
      <ul class="footer__list">
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Help Center</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Release Notes</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Status</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer__unit">
      <h3 class="footer__header">Community</h3>
      <ul class="footer__list">
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Dribble</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Podcast</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer__unit">
      <h3 class="footer__header">Comapny</h3>
      <ul class="footer__list">
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Careers</a></li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">Legal</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="footer__list contact-us">
        <li>
          <h4 class="contact-us__header">Contact Us</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="footer__item"><a href="#" class="footer__link">info@abstract.com</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer last item -->
    <div class="footer__unit footer__unit--last">
      <img src="/img/venus-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="logo" class="footer__logo">
      <ul class="copyright">
        <li class="copyright__item">
          <p class="copyright__text">&copy; Copyright 2022</p>
        </li>
        <li class="copyright__item">
          <p class="copyright__text">Abstract Studio Design, Inc.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="copyright__text">
          <p class="copyright__item">All rights reserved</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I made a screenshot, as you can see the last item (copyright section) wraps while the rest of them stays where they are.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht35u.png

edit: added screenshot

Comment: I am not seeing this problem either on narrowing the viewport on Edge/Windows10 or on using the devtools facility to emulate a mobile. The elements wrap as needed. What system/devices are you using which give you the problem?

Comment: @AHaworth I'm on Firefox 103.0. But yeah I've just tried the same code in Chrome and it's working as intended, wrapping elements correctly. Looks like it's a Firefox issue. Thanks for checking it out.